# What single command in screen, can show a preview of all currently active windows?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Am actively using screen, but wonder, as I've not seen anywhere, hint of a single command to do the above. Can anyone else using screen here, suggest something? Am thinking of a feature similar to what Ctrl+TAB does in Win*.

Comment: Have you tried F3 (previous window) and F4 (next window) to navigate through tabs? I know it works in byobu, not sure if it does in screen.

Comment: @Alex, this is LINUX, not "WinDoze" am talking about XD

Comment: `Byobu` is a `screen` alternative available to some Linux distros.

Comment: @Alex yep! The split features of `byobu` meet my needs :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -ls
```

is this what you need ? or maybe

```
screen -Q windows
```

Comment: Not really. I was looking at something like how you can preview multiple split screens in vim or mc, but where in this case, I wish to preview the contents of each screen buffer during an active screen session. Also, I've noted that your last suggestion is akin to `Ctrl+a w`, which I already use.

Comment: Ah i see sorry. Im not sure of anything off the top of my my head but i will have a small look when im home later. Sorry again. Ah now i read again i see you may use byobu, so no worries, see you